# How does parametrization of the intersection of two surfaces induce a space curve?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Given a two surfaces say: $z=1-y$ and $ x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, we find that they intersect at: $$x^2-2yz=0$$

How is the above a space curve? Is it not just another surface?

And why do we need to introduce a parameter, say $y=t$ , for it to be a space curve? I really don't understand the purpose of parametrization.

Comment: In particular the first surface already gives $z = 1-y$, $z$ parameterized by $y$.  The "intersection" you describe gives $y$ parameterized by $x$.  So the context supplies the kind of parameterization you seek.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: Civil, you typed in something incorrect for the intersection. What you ought to get is $x^2 - 2 y z = 0,$ which is a  circular cone

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for catching my mistake!

Comment: Is the intersection of $x+y=1$ and $x-y=2$ in $\Bbb R^2$ the line $2x=3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes it is, what are you getting at?

Comment: There's all sorts of nonsense being written here. The intersection of these two lines is a point, not another line. When you combine two equations to get another equation, that is not the intersection.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see what you mean, but that is in 2D. In 3D, the intersection of two surfaces is a curve in the xy plane. Maybe a better term for the intersection of surfaces in 3D is :  "Region of intersection"

Comment: No, this is not right at all. In general, it will indeed be a curve, not necessarily in any plane. At any rate, you gave the equation of another surface when you said "they intersect at ... ." All you can say is that their curve of intersection lies  in that surface. Make sure you understand.

Comment: @CivilSigma  Finally,How did you get one of the surfaces (as right circular cone) from equations of  the sphere and plane ? By that procedure why could you not have generated other surfaces with same "concur-line"? This question is relevant to your understanding your own question, or so I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. $$x^2-2yz=0$$ is *not* a space curve. Is it not just another surface but one that shares a commonalty. It is new a cone, a surface similar to the plane and sphere given, with which it shares the same curved intersection. It is one among a set of possible infinitely many surfaces with a common track or locus.

$ z=1-y $ and $ x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, do not intersect at $$x^2-2yz=0.$$

In fact no two surfaces intersect along another surface!

Just as three curved lines can be  concurrent, three surfaces can have a ( I don't know if a proper word exists .."concur-line" :) for lack of one).

If any two of the surfaces is given, the third and indefinitely many more can be set up or found.

$$ (x,y,z) = (\pm \sqrt {2 t ( 1-t)} , t , (1-t) ) \tag{1}$$ is an easy parameterization of the common curved intersection. It has fixed or unique position in 3-space. Here also we can have several possibilities of changing the velocity vector. It is like a race-track. The track is fixed but so many speed / gradient  variations are possible prescribed at any point on common line. The purpose of such parameterization is to find embedding in 3-space for this common line of cutting.

This line gives (x,y,z) coordinates as a function of a *needed* single parameter.

A simpler example. You can imagine all spheres passing through $ x^2 + y^2 = 1$ with their centers on z-axis and varying radii.

EDIT1:

2 errors corrected. $ x^2- 2 y z = 0$ is a cone, not a hyperboloid. But my remarks do not suffer. Other is typo about $\sqrt (..) $ in parameterization.

The red circle is the "concur-line" of the cone, plane and sphere of parameterization (1).

[image: Concurline]

EDIT2:

Picturization of *all* possible coniciods passing through this line (including the above three) is indicated in code given (please make the correction):

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87639/manipulated-surfaces-to-include-parametric3d-plot-of-concurrent-line

The animation shows successive changes, as morphing parameter $lambda$ ( zero for circular cone) is varied:

Double plane $\rightarrow$ oblate ellipsoid $\rightarrow$  hyperboloid of 1 sheet $\rightarrow$ cone $\rightarrow$ sphere $\rightarrow$ hyperboloid of 2 sheets $\rightarrow$  prolate ellipsoid $\rightarrow$ Double plane

This I hope completes an answer to a question  " How is the parameterization of all surfaces inducing a common single space curve of intersection "?

Comment: If you could, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

When "geometric objects" intersect transversely, or in "general position" ,the dimension of their intersection is the dimension of the ambient space (which I am assuming here is $\mathbb R^3$) minus the sum of their respective codimensions, say "Cod" i.e.,

$$Dim (S_1 \cap S_2)_{\mathbb R^3}=Dim(\mathbb R^3)-Cod(S_1)-Cd(S_2) $$

Where $S_1, S_2$ are the two surfaces , giving $$3-1-1=1 $$

So the dimension of the set of points in the intersecting surfaces is $1$, i.e., the intersection is a curve.

Comment: I never knew this. This definitely adds more depth to my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help; let me know if you want a source beyond this :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransversalIntersection.html      .

Comment: And the transversal intersection of homology classes is a well-defined homology class.

Comment: So if 3 surfaces intersect, we have dimension of intersection of single points = zero, ok?

Comment: @Narasimham: I would think that if the intersection is pairwise transversal yes, but give me some time to think. Maybe we could argue by using pairs of surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two surfaces will be a curve.  Here, one surface is the sphere defined by

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \tag 1$$

while the second surface is the plane defined by

$$z=1-y \tag 2$$.

---

Now, the curve of intersection can be defined by a parametric curve

$$\vec r(t)=\hat xx(t)+\hat yy(t)+\hat zz(t)$$

where $t\in [t_1,t_2]$.

And since this curve lies on both the sphere defined by $(1)$ and the plane defined by $(2)$, we have simultaneously

$$z(t)=1-y(t) \tag 3$$

and

$$x^2(t)+y^2(t)+z^2(t)=1 \tag 4$$

Now, $(3)$ and $(4)$ have a common solution

$$x^2(t)+2y^2(t)-2y(t)=0 \tag 5$$

and

$$z(t)=1-y(t) \tag 6$$

---

We rewrite $(5)$ as

$$x^2(t)+2(y(t)-1/2)^2=1/2 \tag 7$$

from which we can see that a parametric curve describing the intersection of $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be expressed as

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t$$

$$y(t)=\frac12+\frac12 \sin t$$

$$z(t)=\frac12-\frac12 \sin t$$

for $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

---

**NOTE:**

The parametric description is not unique and in fact, we need not use a parametric description to describe the curve of intersection.  Here, we could have as easily described the curve in terms of one of the coordinates.   For example, we can write

$$x=\pm\sqrt{y(1-y)}$$

$$y=y$$

$$z=1-y$$

for $0\le y\le 1$.

Comment: note that the OP incorrectly typed the initial conclusion, it should read $x^2 - 2 y z = 0,$ which is a circular cone.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I wasn't using the OP's original conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One final thing, why do we all of a sudden introduce vector functions when our original functions are scalars ( I assume ) ?

Comment: You're quite welcome!! My pleasure.  We don't need to introduce the vector notation. That just makes things a bit more compact to write.