# All surfaces through a common "concur-line"

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Find all second degree surfaces passing through a  common given parameterized space curve of intersection:

$$ (x,y,z) = (\pm \sqrt {2 t ( 1-t)} , t , (1-t) ) $$

using a single variable parameter to describe three surfaces ( sphere, right circular cone and plane) in:

[Concur_line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347696/how-does-parametrization-of-the-intersection-of-two-surfaces-induce-a-space-curv)

Comment: The first part of your Question seems clear, if somewhat broad, but then you add one qualification after another ("using an arbitrary parameter", "when varied... flips through the three surfaces", "including new ones as well").  It would improve the clarity if you instead used your own approach to the problem to illustrate the kind of surfaces and their parameterization that you want.

Comment: I changed it as above. I do not have an own approach, but still trying. If you believe that a single parameter to include all three cases is not possible please let me know. Yves Daoust has  included of two out the three cases already. In a Manipulate command of Mathematica I hope to be able to go from one value of parameter to the other for surfaces sharing common curve of intersection. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

By inspection, we notice that

$$x^2=2yz$$
and
$$y+z=1$$
are independent solutions.

Then $$(y+z-1)^2+\lambda(x^2-2yz)=0$$
includes a (double)
 plane when $\lambda=0$, and a sphere when $\lambda=1$.

Comment: What value of $\lambda $ produces the cone $ x^2= 2 y \,z$? I am looking at Manipulating $ \lambda $ to get all the surfaces

Comment: Obviously $\lambda=\infty$.

Comment: Ok, thanks   $$\lambda(y+z-1)^2+(x^2-2yz)=0$$ suits me fine.

Comment: Or $$(1-\lambda)(y+z-1)^2+\lambda(x^2-2yz)=0$$